# Amazon EC2 - How do I figure out billing for EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

The EC2 pricing page says that Elastic block store is $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage.  But I'm wondering what happens if I only use it for a few days?  How would I be billed for that?

As I understand it, every instance I launch will have an EBS to hold the OS, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it looks like it was answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/197379/amazon-ebs-charges-calculation

Sorry for the bother.